# Django: Creating forms for data linked to a user profile

Tags: django, forms, authentication

I'm trying to save data linked to a user profile using a model with User as a foreign key. I can't figure out a way to create a form that allows adding new instances of the data without having the user name in the form itself. I want to have a form that excludes the user foreign key. Everything works fine until I try to add the user id to the form/data that is about to be saved.

How can I take the logged in user, passed back and forth in the request object, and inject it into the data before I save it?

Comment: Can you post your code or what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a form constructor to give initial values to the form, so like

```
render_to_response(
'template.html', 
{"form" : MyForm(initial={"username": request.user})}, 
context_instance = RequestContext(request)
)
```

you can read more at [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)